# Is river travel to Vientiane and Phnom Penh recommended?

Tags: thailand, vietnam, cambodia, laos, riverboats

I am planning a trip to SE Asia late Sept through Nov. One route idea is fly in to Ho Chi Minh, explore south and delta, road north to Hanoi, fly to Bangkok, road north to Chiang Mai, road to Chiang Rai, to Huay Xia, river boat to Luang Prabang.

Can I then continue by boat to Vientiane?  bryceadams said the road is tough, mountainous, I assume, and flights are a good idea, but is there river transport between these two cities?

And, is it possible to continue on the Mekong Riv. to Phnom Penh?

Alternatively, can I fly Vientiane to Siem Reip and continue by road to Phnom Penh and HCM for return flight?

Appreciate any comments and suggestions on the route.

Comment: There's actually a question buried within that text! =O

Answer (score 2):

There is no regular boat service between Luang Prabang and Vientiane. If you ask around you might find a boat going downstream during high water (rainy season), but it is not something you can count on.

You can find buses from LP to Vientiane, the road is a bit bumpy, but nice scenery along the way.  You could break the trip up with stops along the way.

From Siem Reap to Phnom Penh and on into southern Vietnam is again possible by boat.